# JavaScript multiplication programs do not work normally

Tags: javascript

```js
var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*9 + 1);
var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*9 + 1);
var num_multiple = num1 * num2;

var form = document.querySelector('form');
var input = form.querySelector('input');
var button = form.querySelector('button');
var quesiton = document.querySelector('.p1');
var result = document.querySelector('.p2');

quesiton.textContent = String(num1) + " multiplication " +  String(num2) + " = ? ";

form.addEventListener("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    if(num_multiple === Number(input.value)){
        num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*9 + 1);
        num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*9 + 1);
        num_multiple = num1 * num2;
        quesiton.textContent = String(num1) + " multiplication " +  String(num2) + " = ? ";
        input.value = "";
        result.textContent = "good";
        input.focus();
    }
    else{
        input.value = "";
        result.textContent = "bad";
        input.focus();
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><p class="p1"></p></div>
    <form>
        <input type="text">
        <button>submit</button>
    </form>
    <div><p class="p2"></p></div>
    <script src="multiple.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sorry that I can't speak English so I use a translator to translate it.

The problem is that if the num_multiple and number (input.value) values are equal, "good" comes out very quickly and disappears very quickly. Also, input.focus(); does not work.

The problem is that a new question is written in quesiton even though the num_multiple and number(input.value) values are not equal.

How should I fix the code?

Comment: What about using a `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parentheses at the end of e.preventDefault (to make it a function). Other than that I also updated your code to DRY it out. DRY stands for Don't Repeat Yourself. You had a few lines of duplicate code that I put into a single function `setNumbers()` to make it DRY. I also made the `result.textContent` lines into a single ternary operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

```js
var num1, num2, num_multiple
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var input = form.querySelector('input');
var quesiton = document.querySelector('.p1');
var result = document.querySelector('.p2');

function setNumbers(){
  input.value = "";
  num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
  num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
  num_multiple = num1 * num2;
  quesiton.textContent = String(num1) + " multiplication " + String(num2) + " = ? ";
  input.focus();
}

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var correctAnswer = num_multiple === Number(input.value);
  result.textContent = correctAnswer ? "good" : "bad";
  if(correctAnswer){
    setNumbers()
  }
})

setNumbers()
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="p1"></p>
</div>
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
<div>
  <p class="p2"></p>
</div>
<script src="multiple.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's my first question, and I'm very happy to receive such a wonderful answer and thank you. I have one more question, but if the answer is wrong, the question will be updated with a new question, so can we not update the wrong question again?

Comment: @banghogu Sorry, I don't quite understand. If you have a new question that is similar enough to this current one, you can ask in the comments or edit this question to ask it. If it is different, you might want to just ask a brand new question.

Comment: I'm sorry,  what I was trying to say was that if the answer was wrong (num_multiple === Number (input.value)), I don't want Qesiton.textContent to change to a new question.

Comment: @banghogu I understand now. See my edit. I moved the `num_multiple === Number(input.value);` line to a variable called `correctAnswer`. Then if `correctAnswer` is true, it calls `setNumbers()`.

Comment: That's a great answer. Thank you very very very much. I got a recommendation for this site today and I think it's really good. I hope you have a good day.

Comment: @banghogu You're welcome, have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `e.preventDefault`
i.e do `e.preventDefault()` instead of `e.preventDefault`. This is causing the page to reload (default submit behavior), hence the `input.focus()` not working